# prevent default still res.redirect

Tags: ajax, redirect, preventdefault

```
$('#submit-button').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: window.location.pathname,
       data: {
         "title": $('#event-title').val(),
         "description": $('#event-description').val(),
         "name": $('#owner-name').val(),
       }
   });
});
```

I want to have an ajax request but I also want the button to redirect afterwards to the res.redirect page. It redirects if I remove the prevent default but then it doesn't make the ajax request. How do I make it do both?